# Obtener promedios de datos en coleccion anidada de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy preparando una tabla de reportes y tengo una collection de datos de Laravel en JSON, de esta forma:

```json
{
   "2022-10-04":{
      "Allan Martinez":[
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":13
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":39
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":15
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":38
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":40
         },
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "duration":13
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Como podria obtener un promedio (average) de los datos de Allan Martinez del campo [duration]?

Intente esto por el momento sin exito:

```php
$collection->avg('duration');
```

Pero no devuelve nada, me imagino porque no llega al nivel correcto de la collection, el agrupamiento esta correcto, porque al final lo que ocuparia seria algo como:

```json
{
   "2022-10-04":{
      "Allan Martinez":[
         {
            "date":"2022-10-04",
            "name":"Allan Martinez",
            "average":26.33333
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO: Gracias por leer, al final lo resolvi haciendo un map anidado

Algo asi:

```php
$average = $collection->map(function ($item) {
            return [
                $item->map(function ($child) {                    
                    return[
                        'date' => $child[0]['date'],
                        'name' => $child[0]['name'],
                        'average' => $child->avg('duration'),
                    ];
                }),
            ];            
        });
```